# VBA : variable with multiple value (text)

Tags: vba, excel

Really inexperienced in VBA
I'm trying to built a macro searching differents strings in multiple columns.
I'm searching pattern like : "*[ang]" "*[fre]" "_[ger]

For now, I'm able to find _[ang] in column H, but I think there's a way to find all three patterns with one formula. Important part is to add a note in a specific cell (that's why I use cel.Offset(0, 4))

```
Sub testsearch()
    For Each cel In ActiveSheet.Range("H1:H" & Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        If cel Like "*_[ang]*" Then
            cel.Offset(0, 4) = "_[ang]"
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: `Like` works for simple stuff. For anything non-trivial (like *alternatives*), look into *regular expressions* instead.

Answer (score 2):

What about this..

```
Sub testsearch()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim string_patterns As Variant

    string_patterns = Array("_[ang]", "[fre]", "_[ger]")

    For Each cel In ActiveSheet.Range("H1:H" & Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

        For Each element In string_patterns

            If cel Like "*" & CStr(element) & "*" Then
                cel.Offset(0, 4) = CStr(element)
                Exit For
            End If

        Next element

    Next cel

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You'll probably want to `Exit For` when a match is found.